# common import statement for similar classes

Tags: python

In my app, I have a `model` folder / package.

In that model folder, I generally have a whole bunch of import statements (most of them from SQLAlchemy, such as `String, Integer, Session`, etc.

I find myself writing the same import statements again and again for stuff like `User, Blog, Article, Etc.` and have become pretty sloppy at it.

Understanding that explicit is better than implicit and then going ahead and disregarding that, is there a way to do this once?

Comment: For SQLAlchemy I like to store all my models in one file, along with the db connection details, that when whereever I import its simply dbdefs.model_name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this probably isnt what you want but who knows

## common_imports.py

```
 from sqlalchemy import Model,String,...
```

in other scripts just do

```
from common_imports import *
```

[edit]
**actually  I came up with a really awful and hacky way to do what you want**

a really hacky way to do it might be something like

```
\root_of_package
    -main.py
    \models
       -__init__.py
       -model1.py
       -model2.py
```

then in `models\__init__.py`

```
from sqlalchemy import String,Integer,...
from glob import glob
Base = ...
for fname in glob("%s/*.py"%dirname(__file__)):
    with open(fname) as f:
        eval(f.read())
__all__ = locals()
```

then in `models/model1.py`

```
#just use all the imports/locals from __init__.py as if they already existed
#this will be hellish if you use an IDE that checks for errors for you
class Model1(Base):
      id = Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
      ...
```

then in `main.py`

```
from models import Model1
```

Comment: one last disclosure to be very explicit this 2nd method i detailed is __very very very__ hacky and I would never ever ever recommend anyone ever use it in the real world for actual code ... it was more a thought experiment

Comment: will be accepting this based on the great hack, though I will probs be using answer 2 instead. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I do this in one of my applications.

```
# approot/m.py

from models.model import String, Integer, Session, (etc)

# Otherwise blank!
```

Then in everything else:

```
import m
```

Then you can do `m.String`, `m.Integer`, `m.Session` and etc. This also means I can further encapsulate my code so that later when I write up user models I can just add to `m.py`

```
from models.user import User, Group, PermissionSet
```

and continue to access `m.User`, `m.Group` and etc.

Comment: hehe :P ... great answer :P I thought about doing the namespace in my example but meh

Comment: @JoranBeasley I think it was actually AnttiHaapala that showed me this when he posted some snippet of his own project. I stole it immediately.